# Is possible to drop a database in ADO.NET or create a new one

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I've been search for example to drop a database and create a new one in C# using ADO.NET or etc for SQL Server.

The problem is I need to create a instance of a new database for every new licensee, the customer wants a separate database for each new licensee, I've never tried this before and I'm finding it difficult to gauge the feasibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. It's actually an article on MSDN knowledge base.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283

You basically just connect to 'master' or any database really, and send a SQL Command to create the database.

That should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be looking at SQL SMO for this.

There are examples everywhere on how this works. For example, check out this one [(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CreateSQLDV.aspx).](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CreateSQLDV.aspx)

Anything you can do manually in SQL Management Studio you can do programatically, with SMO.